# Unable to log in to Magent 2 backend - login times out

Tags: backend, session, admin-login

I am unable to log in to my admin panel, the login keeps timing out whatever I do. Our test system had the same problem but a reboot solved the problem this time nothing seems to help. 
I use varnish and nginx. I have the following error in the log:

2020/04/16 09:25:05 [error] 819#819: *1859 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 85.203.44.29, server: domain.us, request: "POST /domainadmin/admin/index/index/key/d6d372ad21c94d34761ce46c523430b8df2fe764ed9e7c8d902198396d6fb066/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/domainadmin/admin/index/index/key/d6d372ad21c94d34761ce46c523430b8df2fe764ed9e7c8d902198396d6fb066/", host: "domain.us", referrer: "https://domain.us/domainadmin/admin/index/index/key/d6d372ad21c94d34761ce46c523430b8df2fe764ed9e7c8d902198396d6fb066/"

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an indexing issue, doing a reindex solved the problem.